# grails default constraints

Tags: grails, groovy

Assume I have a Grails domain object like this:

```
class Todo {

    String name
    String status

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false)
    }    
}
```

What are the default constraints on a field if:

- It's listed in the `constraints` block e.g. name
- It isn't listed in the `constraints` block, e.g. status

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, Siegfried is right, nullable: false is the only thing that gets set by default.  You can take a look at the domain class artefact and interrogate the constrained properties in the console:

```
grailsApplication.getDomainClass("Todo").constrainedProperties.each { propName, constraints  ->
    println "$propName : ${constraints.appliedConstraints.name}"
}
```

Prints:

```
status : [nullable]
priority : [nullable]
name : [blank, nullable]
```

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know it is only `nullable: false` in both cases.